# Media Library Items: can I specify a path that is relative from the "Media.FileFolder" setting?

Tags: media-library

When I use the file system to store items from the Media Library, I can see that each item stores either an absolute path or one that is relative from the webroot - not a path that is relative from the Media.FileFolder setting.

This means that I cannot use the same data in dev and live if they have a different Media.FileFolder (which they do).

Is there a way to configure Sitecore so that the path of every item in the Media Library is relative to the Media.FileFolder?

Comment: Add virtual directory in IIS how it is described here: https://www.bugdebugzone.com/2016/08/storing-sitecore-media-in-shared-file.html

Comment: I'll try it on Monday and I'll come back.

Comment: This works for me! If you write it as an answer I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to configure virtual folder in IIS that will point to absolute location on your server, e.g.: "SharedMedia" folder that point to "C:\SharedMedia".
Then you will be able to configure Sitecore use this virtual folder as location for media files:

```
<setting name="Media.UploadAsFiles" value="true">
<setting name="Media.FileFolder" value="/SharedMedia">
```

There are more detail how to do it in [this article](https://www.bugdebugzone.com/2016/08/storing-sitecore-media-in-shared-file.html).